# Remove the 0 from hours

Tags: javascript

```
hour: function () {
   var hour = (options.twentyfour === true) ? d.getHours() : (d.getHours() + 11) % 12 + 1;
    hour = (options.padzero === true) ? (hour < 10 ? "0" + hour : "" + hour) : h
    return hour;
 },
```

How could I remove the 0 from the hours when the time is 01 pm for example? I think I would have to remove this `"0" + hour` and reformat the code but I don't really know how

Comment: the second line of the function `hour = (options.padzero === true)...` is adding the zero-padding. If you comment out or remove that line the zero should go away

Comment: Alter the code! Look at what it is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of that function is concerned with padding a 0 for hours.  If you want to get rid of that functionality the function can become

```
hour: function () {
  return (options.twentyfour === true) ? d.getHours() : (d.getHours() + 11) % 12 + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove leading zero with a regexp.

```
var hour = "01";
hour.replace(/^0+/, '')
```